# command to print out list of folders from multiple drives

Tags: command-line

Is there a CLI command to print out in alphabetical order (but in one single txt or spreadsheet) the list of folders contained in different hard drives?

For example, lets say I have this configuration:

```
/sda/Alfa/File 1
/sdb/Bravo/File 5
/sdb/Bravo/File 20
/sdc/Delta/File 14
/sdc/Delta/File 11
```

What i would like to output is a TXT or Spreadsheet file where folders are listed in alphabetical order, somethings like:

```
File 1
File 5
File 11
File 14
File 20
```

Is this something I can do from the CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) with [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1.html):

```
find /sda /sdb /sdc -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort
```

For example:

```
$ tree sd[a-c]
sda
└── Alfa
    └── File 1
sdb
└── Bravo
    ├── File 20
    └── File 5
sdc
└── Delta
    ├── File 11
    └── File 14
$ find sd[a-c] -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort
File 1
File 11
File 14
File 20
File 5
```

Note that *this* is what is typically meant by alphabetical order, more precisely stated as lexicographic order. (`5` the character does not come before `1` the character, so `5` the string cannot come before `14` the string - `05`, however, will.)

---

Explanation:

`find` is a program for finding things.

- `-type f` indicates we want regular files, and not directories (or other special files).
- The usual output of `find` is the path of the file, so we would get `sda/Alfa/File 1`, but using `-printf '%f\n'`, we tell `find` to print only the filename.

Comment: Can i use it also for folders?

Comment: @simplemind sure, remove the `-type f`.